# Tikz arrow starting exactly in the center

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have the following problem. I am using the `tikz` package to draw figures. I am drawing some sort of a data structure. This includes having nodes and lines which connect nodes. Sometimes, a line has to start with a dot and end with an arrow. I have the following code (using `arrows` and `patterns` `tikz` libraries):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [internal/.style={rectangle,draw},
       bmp/.style={rectangle,draw,pattern=north east lines},
       ]
      \node(root)     at ( 0.00, 0.00)                           {\verb=root=};
      \node(in1)      at ( 0.00,-0.60)          [internal,minimum width=3mm,label=left:I1]        {};
      \draw[-stealth](root)--(in1);

      \node(cn1)      at ( 0.00,-1.2)           [internal,minimum width=6mm,label=left:C1]        {};
      \node(cn1bmp)   at (-0.15,-1.2)           [bmp,minimum width=3mm]             {};
      \node(cn1arr1)  at ( 0.15,-1.2)           [internal,minimum width=3mm]        {};
      \draw[*-stealth](in1.mid)--(cn1);

      \node(k1)       at ( 0.50,-1.8)                                               {$k_1$};
      \draw[*-stealth](cn1arr1.mid)--(k1);

      \node(cas)      at ( 0.8,-0.20)                              {\verb=CAS=};
      \draw[->, shorten >=2pt](cas)--(in1);

      \node(lab)      at (-0.70,-1.80) [internal]     {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Trie examples}
\label{f-tries}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following picture:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the arrow pointing to `k1` (corresponding to `\draw[*-stealth](cn1arr1.mid)--(k1);`) starts a little bit to the right. When I have more arrows, this looks nasty - they all seem to have offsets in various directions.

Is there any way to force the arrow to start in exactly the center (`cn1arr1.center` doesn't work - it puts it too low)?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question to make the sample code a complete working example, starting from `\documentclass` and including all the libraries necessary? That makes it a lot easier for everyone who wants to try out the code.

Comment: You're right, I should do that. I'm on it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\verb` to get `tt` font, simply use `\texttt{..}` instead.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Should that be so in general, or just in figures? The LNCS styleguide says that I should use the `verbatim` package for code examples.

Comment: @axel22: For source code you should use verbatim, but it isn't required for normal words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple solution: Use the `shorten < = <length>` syntax, which will move the arrow tip (the circle in your case) a specified length along the path. Using

```
\draw[*-stealth,shorten <=-2.5pt](cn1arr1.center)--(k1);
```

works quite well in this case.

A more correct way would be to define a new arrow tip using `\pgfdeclarearrow{start name}{end name}{extend code}{arrow tip code}`, where the `extend code` (which moves the arrow tip along the line) is left empty. Here's an implementation that is based on the original `*` arrow tip code, so the circle diameter will be identical to the original one, but it will be centered on the start of the line:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{new*}{new*}{}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{+4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Interesting - I would have thought that `shorten` shortens the line in the direction it is pointing to. However, what it does is, it just lifts it directly up a little bit, when its starting point is set to `center`. Thanks!

Comment: @axel22: You're right, `shorten` does move the tip along the line. Try setting a large positive value to see it move, and also to see that the actual line starts at the specified point (actually it doesn't start *exactly* at the specified point because the line is shortened a bit by the arrow tip command, but it's pretty close).