# Inconsistent TikZ multipart node anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following example, why aren't the node anchors placed consistently?

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
  font=\tt, >= stealth, every picture/.style={thick}, pointer/.style={*->},
  box/.style={draw, inner sep=2ex, fill=black!10, rounded corners,
    rectangle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split ignore empty parts=false, rectangle split horizontal}}
\tikzpicture[every node/.append style={at end}]
  \node[box] (1) {};
  \draw[pointer] (1.text) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north,box] (2) {};
  \draw[pointer] (2.text) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {1};
  \draw[pointer] (2.two) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {2};
  \draw[pointer] (1.two) -- +(1,0) node[anchor=base west,box] (3) {};
  \draw[pointer] (3.text) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {3};
  \draw[pointer] (3.two) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {4};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

Ideally, I'd like the black dots to be exactly in the center.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure you take the good way. In the pgfmanual, you can see that centers of the different parts are not given. I think the center of a part for example "one" is `$(1.west)!.5!(1.one split)$`. I write rapidly the next code and it's possible to write something more elegant.

**Update  version 2** : I found a way to create the coordinates of the centers for each part but I can't find how to create the circles with the style. (c1 3) désigne the center of the first part of the node (3). There are some modifications in the code like `at end`

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart,calc}

\tikzset{
  font=\tt, 
  >= stealth, 
  every picture/.style={thick},
  box/.style={at end,
              draw, 
              inner sep=2ex, 
              fill=black!10, 
              rounded corners,
              rectangle, 
              rectangle split, 
              rectangle split parts=2,
              rectangle split ignore empty parts=false, 
              rectangle split horizontal,
              append after command={%
              \pgfextra{%
                \let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode} 
                coordinate (c1 \mainnode) at ($(\mainnode.west)!.5!(\mainnode.one split)$)
                coordinate (c2 \mainnode) at ($(\mainnode.one split)!.5!(\mainnode.east)$)}}}
\tikzpicture
  \node[box] (1) {};
   \draw[->] (c1 1) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north,box] (2) {};
   \draw[->] (c1 2) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {1};
   \draw[->] (c2 2) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {2};
   \draw[->] (c2 1) -- +(1,0)  node[anchor=west,box] (3) {};
   \draw[->] (c1 3) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {3};
   \draw[->] (c2 3) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {4};  
   \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{\draw[fill=black] (c1 \i)circle(2pt) (c2 \i)circle(2pt);}
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

Difference with Marc's solution

```
\node[box] (1) { };
\draw[] (1.one|-1.west) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] ($(1.west)!.5!(1.one split)$)circle(2pt);
```

gives [image]

**Update version 3.** It's possible to draw the circle directly but in this case you can't draw the arrows at the same time. The code is interesting and perhaps someone can find a good idea for the arrows (only arrows when we use `box`)

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart,calc}

\tikzset{
  font=\tt, 
  >= stealth, 
  every picture/.style={thick},
  box/.style={
              draw, 
              inner sep=2ex, 
              fill=black!10, 
              rounded corners,
              rectangle, 
              rectangle split, 
              rectangle split parts=2,
              rectangle split ignore empty parts=false, 
              rectangle split horizontal,
              append after command={%
                \pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode 
                \coordinate (c1 \mainnode) at ($(\mainnode.west)!.5!(\mainnode.one split)$);
                \coordinate (c2 \mainnode) at ($(\mainnode.one split)!.5!(\mainnode.east)$);
                \draw[fill=black] (c1 \mainnode)circle(2pt) (c2 \mainnode)circle(2pt);}
                }}}
\tikzpicture
   \node[box] (1) {};
   \path (c1 1)     -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north,box] (2) {};
   \draw[->] (c1 2) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {1};
   \draw[->] (c2 2) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {2};
   \path (c2 1)     -- +(1,0)  node[anchor=west,box] (3) {};
   \draw[->] (c1 3) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {3};
   \draw[->] (c2 3) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {4};
   \draw[->] (c1 1) --  (2.north);
   \draw[->] (c2 1) --  (3.west); 
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

We get the same result.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks! `:-)` If only one could somehow automate the center calculation… hmmm

Comment: Not obvious ! Perhaps it's possible to add some code to define the centers after the creation of the nodes. No idea actually, it will be useful to modify `box/.style` to do this.

Comment: @Altermundus: Note that the third box (the rightmost one) in your code for **Update version 2** is placed a bit above the first one (the top left one), while the two really should be aligned horizontally. I found that if you change "base west" to just "west", the two ends up aligned in the same vertical placement, although I don't know why this works (why?). The same method also works for the code under **Update version 3**, but then the arrow connecting the two boxes will be pointing slightly downwards instead (why?).

Comment: @Altermundus: Why does each arrow get rendered with a point in its start position in your **Update version 2** code? I have looked at every line of the code but I can't see anything that would cause them to be rendered like that. They don't get rendered that way in your **Update version 3** code.

Comment: @Altermundus: I would like the size of my box to depend on the local coordinate system; in fact, I would like the two parts of the box to be split with one unit in the x-direction. How can I achieve that? I start my tikz picture with `\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(.035\textwidth,0)},y={(0,.035\textwidth)}]`, but x and y are not known when the box style is defined, so `inner sep` cannot be determined directly.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I used the code from morbusg but you are right if you want to align the first boxes you need to use `west`and not `base west`. To understand you can look at the pgfmanual section `Shape Library`. I will update my answer.

Comment: You can use `\mainnode.mid` instead of `$(\mainnode.west)!.5!(\mainnode.one split)$`. Unfortunately, `\mainnode.two mid` is not defined...

Comment: Also, if you have many parts and want to get the middle of all of those parts, you can use `$(\mainnode.west)!0.5!(\mainnode.one split)$` for the first one, `$(\mainnode.west)!1.5!(\mainnode.one split)$` for the second one, `$(\mainnode.west)!2.5!(\mainnode.one split)$` for the third one etc. In that way you just need to change one digit! :)

Answer (score 6):

It looks as if this is a bug. Two things are going on. The pointer style results in the wrong positions for the start of the arrows. On top of that, the positioning inside the text parts of the boxes looks suspicious. In the following I show how you can get around these problems by using a normal arrow and by computing (what appears to be) the centre of the `two` text parts.

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  font=\tt, >= stealth, every picture/.style={thick}, pointer/.style={*->},
  box/.style={draw, inner sep=2ex, fill=black!10, rounded corners,
    rectangle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split ignore empty parts=false, rectangle split horizontal}}
\tikzpicture[every node/.append style={at end}]
  \node[box] (1) {};
  \draw[->] (1.mid) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north,box] (2) {};
  \draw[->] (2.mid) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {1};
  \draw[->] (2.two|-2.east) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {2};
  \draw[->] (1.two|-1.east) -- +(1,0) node[anchor=base west,box] (3) {};
  \draw[->] (3.mid) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {3};
  \draw[->] (3.two|-3.east) -- +(0,-1) node[anchor=north] {4};
\endtikzpicture
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! `:)` (I'm out of votes *again,* but I promise to upvote it ASAP) `:)`

Comment: I wouldn't say that the arrows start in the *wrong* place, just not in the place one might expect. This has been covered before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/tikz-arrow-starting-exactly-in-the-center

Comment: `2.two|-2.east` is not the exact center of the two part !

Comment: @Jake: trying out your solution in the linked answer (the defined `new*`) leads to some… uh… “interesting results” with my example.

Comment: @Altermundus I noticed the position wasn't exactly the centre, which is why I wrote _(what appears to be)_. I wasn't aware of the `one split` coordinate. It's not mentioned in the `pgf` manual, which is all I'm going to read: you won't see me reading the source files:-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen In the pgfmanual you have `text split`, I try `one split` but it's a lucky try.