# array of linked lists like in data structure

Tags: lists

I want to implement an array of linked lists in La TeX like it appeared in data structure (graphic):

the array elements are the numbers{1,2,3}
and  every number in the array is ahead of linked list{the first element in array is the head of the linked list a->b->null, where a and b are the nodes in the linked list, and so on to the other array elements}

|1|->a->b->null

|2|->c->null

|3|->d->null

can you help me in this?

Comment: Are you trying to draw this as a graphic, or just as something in text? Are you looking for a way to input this using a macro (say) `\linkedlist{1={a,b,null},2={c,null},3={d,null}}` and the output should be automated?

Comment: I want to draw it as a graphic

Comment: You can find some examples here: [some-problems-drawing-linked-lists-with-tikzs-matrix-library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/some-problems-drawing-linked-lists-with-tikzs-matrix-library) or [tikz-library-for-computer-science](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45376/tikz-library-for-computer-science/45381#45381)

Comment: Also you might be interested in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44267/1410

Comment: @morbusg or at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45381/10274).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried to write a code which provides the simplest interface:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{a,b,null}, 2/{c,null}, 3/{d,null}} {
   \node[array element] (aux) at (0,-\index) {\index};
   \LinkedList{\list}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

This is the complete source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
node of list/.style = { 
             draw, 
             fill=orange!20, 
             minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,
             node distance=6mm
   },
link/.style = {
     -stealth,
     shorten >=1pt
     },
array element/.style = {
    draw, fill=white,
    minimum width = 6mm,
    minimum height = 10mm
  }
}

\def\LinkedList#1{%
  \foreach \element in \list {
     \node[node of list, right = of aux, name=ele] {\element};
     \draw[link] (aux) -- (ele);
     \coordinate (aux) at (ele.east);
  } 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{a,b,null}, 2/{c,null}, 3/{d,null}} {
   \node[array element] (aux) at (0,-\index) {\index};
   \LinkedList{\list}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the above is not the standard way of representing linked lists. I prefer this one instead:

[image: Result2]

Which is obtained simply replacing the definition of `\LinkedList` above with this one:

```
\def\LinkedList#1{%
  \foreach \element in \list {
     \node[node of list, right = of aux, name=ele] {\element};
     \node[node of list, name=aux2, anchor=west] at ([xshift=-.4pt] ele.east) {};
     \draw[link] (aux) -- (ele);
     \coordinate (aux) at (aux2);
   }
   \fill (aux) circle(2pt);
}
```

and removing the `null` element in the list specification, i.e. the main loop is now:

```
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{a,b}, 2/{c}, 3/{d}} {
```

---

A small addition, if future readers need this kind of behavior:

```
\foreach [count=\i] \index/\list in {1/{a,b}, 20/{c}, 50/{d}} {
    \node[array element] (aux) at (0,-\i) {\index};
    \LinkedList{\list}
}
```

outputs the linked list with only the needed array cells rendered, eg.

[image: a example linked list]

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this solution for a presentation (beamer class) but it appears its resizing the squares for the array, for example if the array is 1, 200, 5000, each square has a different size. Also, Is there a way to replace the circles with a custom character?

Comment: @Aram For the size of the squares, modify `array element/.style` and set, for example, `minimum width=12mm`, or the required amount. For the second question, change `\fill (aux) circle(2pt);` by `\node at (aux) {*};`, for example (replace the `*` for the desired character).