# Array of linked list

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, lists, pstricks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array of linked lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86766/array-of-linked-lists)

I want to implement an array of linked lists in latex:

the array elements are the numbers{1,2,3} and every number in the array is ahead of linked list{the first element in array is the head of the linked list a->b->null, where a and b are the nodes in the linked list, and so on to the other array elements}

|1|->a->b->null

|2|->c->null

|3|->d->null

can you help me in this?

lists latex-project

Comment: Are you trying to draw this as a graphic, or just as something in text? Are you looking for a way to input this using a macro (say) `\linkedlist{1={a,b,null},2={c,null},3={d,null}}` and the output should be automated?

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: [related?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45376/tikz-library-for-computer-science/45381#45381)