# TikZ always starts from Center

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to use TikZ to draw a diagram, I used the example below, but I see that I could not start the beginning point from a bit left of the page. I checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/tikz-arrow-starting-exactly-in-the-center) question but it's too long and I don't see a solution for my problem there

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-15,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-14,1);
\draw[black] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you mentioning the paragraph indent maybe? Put `\noindent` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and please let us know if that fixes it.